# Assigning JS in code behind for textbox to receive focus

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net

In my code I'am inserting new record to database then reloading list
and only thing i would like to do now is to set focus to TextBox that represents new record. In code behind after reloading list I'am able to obtain reference to that TextBox.
 So basically I need to register script that after load will fire and set focus to that control, but I'm not sure how to do that, can you help guys ? :)

```
{
            TextBox txt = (TextBox)lastRow.Cells[1].Controls[0];

            //Here I need to assign script
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your question, but if I do, this Javascript should do the job:

```
document.getElementById("myTextbox").focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using asp.net pages

on page constructor you can subscribe to `Loaded` event and then call the `textbox.Focus()`

```
public MyPageName()
{
     this.Loaded += myloadedEventHandler;
}

void myloadedEventHandler(object sender,EventArgs args)
{
     textBox.Focus();
}
```